# Uniformly Distributed Marginal Density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution, density-function

A point $(X,Y)$ in the Cartesian plane is uniformly distributed within the unit circle
if $X$ and $Y$ have joint density:

$$f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{π} & \mathrm{x^2+y^2} \le 1  \\ 
0 & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Find the marginal densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$ and state whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent or not. Provide a mathematical justification for your answer.

**I am really confused, I don't know how to set up the two integrals, please help :)**

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840389/marginal-distribution-of-the-unit-disk

Comment: The post linked by BGM is not a good one.